# Как записать данные из массива в файл с++

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

```
//Как записать данные из массива в файл с++

//У меня то не записывается не чего, то какие - то иероглифы
//нужна помощь с тем как записать данные из массива char в файл

void registration() {
    char username[20];
    char password[20];

    bool match = 0;

    bool successful = 0;
    do//Create a password, check if the user entered the same password twice.
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\t\t\t\t_________________________Registration_________________________" << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\t\tInput UserName: ";
        cin >> username;
        cout << "\t\t\t\tInput Password: ";
        cin >> password;
        cout << "\t\t\t\tConfirm Input Password: ";
        string password_r = " ";
        cin >> password_r;
        if (password_r == password)
            successful = 1;
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "TWO PASSWORDS DID NOT MATCH, TRY AGAIN." << endl <<
                "ENTER 1 TO CONTINUE." << endl;;
            bool x = 0;
            cin >> x;
            if (x == 1)
                registration();
        }
    } while (successful == 0);


    FILE* FileIn = fopen("records.txt", "a");
    

    char(username);
    char(password);

    char(fwrite(username, sizeof(char), 10, FileIn));
    fwrite(password, sizeof(char), 10, FileIn);

    
    match = 1;
    fclose(FileIn);

}
```

Comment: А что это вы такое интересное делаете — ` char(username);`? Зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите записать как *бинарные* данные, или как *текстовые*? Если бинарные — то записями по 20 байт или нет?

Если же простым текстом, то так же, как на консоль — только в файл :)

```
fprintf(FileIn,"%s\n%s\n",username,password);
```

Comment: Все ровно иероглифы в файле

Comment: А если вводите английскими буквами?

Comment: так я вожу английскими буквами

Comment: Что конкретно вводите, как выглядит содержимое файла? Как выглядит вывод на экран, типа, `cout << username`? Похоже, проблема у вас не в выводе... Да, вы так и не ответили — вам нужен текстовый вывод или бинарный?

Comment: Я вожу hello, а в файле 敨汬൯栊汥潬਍   мне нужен текстовой

Comment: Что-то вы не так делаете. Или просматриваете файл в неверной кодировке, например... Или недоговариваете. Положите полный  свой код на какой-то файлообменник и дайте ссылку.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14aoGwzhQcBG0C_soJW6JVSlhO6LJqUxt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ну, чтоб нормально скомпилировать, пришлось, как положено, перенести `using namespace std` после всех `#include`, но после этого получился нормальный текстовый файл, как и требовалось, с соответствующими словами. Похоже, вы его просто как-то не так просматриваете. Чем вы смотрите содержимое файла? Кстати, еще, как вариант, дайте получающийся файл посмотреть

Comment: Спасибо брат выручил

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось Вот так это сделать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


void registration();


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    registration();

    return 0;
}


void registration() {
    char username[20];
    char password[20];

    bool match = 0;

    bool successful = 0;
    do//Create a password, check if the user entered the same password twice.
    {
        system("cls");
        std::cout << "\t\t\t\t_________________________Registration_________________________" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t\t\t\tInput UserName: ";
        std::cin >> username;
        std::cout << "\t\t\t\tInput Password: ";
        std::cin >> password;
        std::cout << "\t\t\t\tConfirm Input Password: ";
        std::string password_r = " ";
        std::cin >> password_r;
        if (password_r == password)
            successful = 1;
        else
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "TWO PASSWORDS DID NOT MATCH, TRY AGAIN." << std::endl <<
                "ENTER 1 TO CONTINUE." << std::endl;;
            bool x = 0;
            std::cin >> x;
            if (x == 1)
                registration();
        }
    } while (successful == 0);

    std::ofstream Fout;
    Fout.open("records.txt", std::ofstream::app);

    if (!Fout.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Что-то пошло не так..." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        Fout << username << " : " << password << std::endl;
    }
    
    Fout.close();
}
```